# VSCODE Live Server https not wanting to start

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use an SSL certificate for the liveserver extension. It is self-signed, trusted, and verified to be working (added in apache).

However the extension does not want to start no matter what, unless https is disabled.
I am also using port 8080, but that does not matter. (Certificate is for "localhost")

How can I fix this?

```json
{
    "liveserver.settings.port": 8080,
    "liveServer.settings.https": {
        "enable": true, //set it true to enable the feature.
        "cert": "/home/me/primary.crt", //full path of the certificate
        "key": "/home/me/private.key", //full path of the private key
        "passphrase": "1234"
    }
}
```

Comment: This thread is more about software support and not coding, but have you tried re-installing the extension and for good measure re-generating the certificate? Why apache accepts it, I have no idea, but different software doing similar things doesn't always yield the same result.

Comment: @SimpleCoder Late answer, but it turns out to be some sort of bug with the extension and reinstalling it actually helped. I forgot to close/answer this question. You can submit an answer and I will mark it as accepted.